# Android permission popup doesn't show while opening an app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I am trying to create a music app. this app requires write external storage permission. I am having android 13 Api 33. i added uses permission in manifest file and main.xml file like below,

in manifest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MusicPlayer"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayList"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Player"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FavouriteActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
in may Main.XMl file
```

`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    requestRunTimePermission()

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    openMainActivity()

}
fun openMainActivity(){
    binding.shuffleBtn.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,Player::class.java))
    }
    binding.favouriteBtn.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,FavouriteActivity::class.java))
    }
    binding.playListBtn.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,PlayList::class.java))
    }
}



private fun requestRunTimePermission():Boolean{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),13)
        return false
    }
    return true

}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,permissions: Array<out String>,grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == 13){
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permisiion granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),13)
        }
    }
}
```

}`

the above code dosen't add permission to my app.

I tried above code on my app. it doesn't display permission popup while opening the app.

Comment: On recent Android versions external storage permissions are simply ignored by Android as those permissions are deprecated.

Comment: Make sure you are testing on Android 13 device and then add two more Permissions which are 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
if these permissions are not granted so it will come on when you will run app after uninstalling or clearing data

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeting API level 33 then you can't use the External storage Permission which will not be granted. Instead, use the below permissions.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />`

Comment: These three permissions have nothing to do with the old WRITE permission. They are hence no replacement.

Answer (score 0):

> > this app requires write external storage permission. I am having android 13 Api 33.

No. That permission is not needed on Android 13 devices.

You have WRITE permission by default.